# Limit the results of a active record find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a table with employees (id, name, role) and a relations table bosses (employee_id, superior_id; both foreign_keys to employees.id to employees).

Now if a employee logs in, I only want to show his/her employees; an admin (role=admin) can see all employees.

For the admin it's easy:

```
Employee.find(:all) #to list them
Employee.find(params[:id] #to find one
```

Is there an easy way to limit the results on just my employees?

Like add always a condition

```
where employees.id in
 (select id from bosses where superior_id = #{User.current_user.employee})
```

if role is not admin.

**Additional Comment**

Could you think of a more general solution, where every time a call the find method in active record, it checks for the current_user and returns only the elements, he/she should see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Employee.all(:joins => :bosses, :conditions => {:superior_id => User.current_user.employee})
```

Comment: yes, this solves it, at least once, but actually I'm still looking for a more general solution. Like every time I call a find, it limits the user on the people, he/she has access to.

Comment: You showed me the right path. I used the code from the named scope, to write a scoping for myself

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
@boss = Boss.find(params[:id], :include => [:employees])
```

To fetch a boss and their employees. Then use

```
@boss.employees
```

to get that boss's employees.